# Subclass inheriting an enum: ClassNotDefinedError

Tags: java, inheritance, enums

Status quo ante:

```
public class A {
    public enum C { ONE, TWO, THREE }
}
```

Now, let's pretend we really, really don't like the name "A". So we want to rename it to "B". Trouble is, this is a library and we want to remain backwards compatible. Well, that ought to be possible, right?

```
public class B {
    public enum C {ONE, TWO, THREE }
}
```

and in a different file:

```
@Deprecated
public class A extends B {
}
```

Now the problem is that old code will get a complaint that A$C does not exist.

This seems insoluble unless I leave the enum in class A and have B extend A, which doesn't really help us get rid of A.

Comment: Why can't you `import A.C;` and just not look at your imports?

Comment: The big problem here is really binary compatibility. A.C will never be “the same” as B.C. And because enums are final, I can’t just have an A.C that extends B.C.

There may be no solution.